# Ventrilo Status on your website

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I'm looking for some examples of how you would show the status of a ventrilo server on your website.  What I would like is the ability to show who is logged on and what channel they are logged into.  I have found sites that you can purchase, but would like to either find a open source or free solution.

If there is not a solution already in place, some information on how this would be accomplished in either php or c#/asp.net, as I do have both options available.

Edit:
Now, I would really like to know how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ventrilo themselves provide some PHP server status scripts you could build on:

http://www.ventrilo.com/dlprod.php?id=201

Answer (score -1):

REST API that can be used with any language, not only C# or PHP
http://tools.cleanvoice.ru/ventrilostatus

It returns data in CVP format https://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Channel_Viewer_Protocol

#### Javascript Example (based on http://mumble-widget.guildbit.com)

https://jsfiddle.net/obbwgLu1/

#### PHP Example

```
<?php

$address = "";
$port = 3784;
$api_url = "https://api.cleanvoice.ru/ventrilo/?address={$address}&port={$port}";

if ( $response = @file_get_contents($api_url) )
{
    if ( $json = json_decode($response) )
    {
        if (isset($json->error))
        {
            echo $json->message;
        }
        else
        {
            echo render_cvp_channel($json->root);
        }
    }
}

function render_cvp_channel($channel)
{
    // display channel name
    $html = sprintf("<b>%s</b>", $channel->name);
    $html .= '<ul>';

    // display users
    foreach ($channel->users as $u)
    {
        $html .= sprintf("<li><i>%s</i></li>", $u->name);
    }

    // display subchannels
    foreach ($channel->channels as $c)
    {
        $html .= render_cvp_channel($c);
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}

?>
```

[image]